# Controls in activity auto hide when set 9 path window background in Android

Tags: android, background, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with some `TextView` and `ImageView` on it. When set window background color with BLACK, everything is ok. But when set window background with 9 path png image, all controls in `RelativeLayout` auto hide in run mode although them visible in design mode. Why?[image: background image]

Comment: Can you attach your 9-patch drawable?

Comment: @rom4ek, i had added my 9-patch